# Good way of storing UserProfile information and preventing database call on every page load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to create a way to store user's profile information in either session or cache and be able to have that information on hand every time the page loads to prevent calling the database every time we load a page.  I want to be able to put some of these values in a shared layout (so i can put the user's name in the upper right hand corner etc.).  At the top of my master page layout I have the following:

```
@{  

    Domain.Entities.UserProfile user = (Domain.Entities.UserProfile)HttpContext.Current.Session[Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString()]; 
}
```

I use values like `user.FirstName` in my master page. When a user logs in I set the session.  Is there a better way of doing this?  If I am logged out and I just navigate to a member only page, the `[Authorize]` filter is bypassed and I get an error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` because my user profile is not stored in session yet. I do not store any sensitive information in the session like a UserId or anything, just the users name, profile image url etc. I feel there may be a better way of doing such a task.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your user information in the authentication cookie. Keep in mind that the cookie will be sent back and forth from the client with every request. So if there's a lot of information to be stored maybe that's not the right way.

Check the step 4 of this document that explains how to store additional user data in the cookie http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/introduction/forms-authentication-configuration-and-advanced-topics-cs

Then in your master page, you can have something like this

```
@{  

if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    //Your code goes here, no way user data is null.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static class as an interface to get the user properties, which will be stored in the session state.

```
public class UserData{

    public static Domain.Entities.UserProfile GetUser(){
        string username;
        try{
            username = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            //  just in case
            throw new AuthenticationException("The user isn't authenticated!");
        }

        var user = HttpContext.Current.Session[username] as Domain.Entities.UserProfile;
        if(user == null){
            user = //   get data from database
            HttpContext.Current.Session[username] = user;
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

Then, in your methods you can use it like this:

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    UserProfile user = UserData.GetUser();

    //Your code goes here, no way user data is null.
}
```

Or in controllers:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index(){

    UserProfile user = UserData.GetUser();

    return //stuff
}
```

Note: I made this without being able to test, but I hope you get the point :)